# Encountered a "StateError (Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close)" upon the attempt to log in with Google

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using the [flutter_firebase_login](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login) example from the official GitHub repository of **flutter_bloc**. My goal is to store supplementary user data in the Firestore database after a successful Google login, specifically for first-time users, in addition to their *email*, *displayName*, and *photoURL*.

Specifically, I'm storing the following fields in the **user** collection.

- firstName
- lastName
- email
- title
- company
- location
- bio
- interests
- profilePicture

With that said, the exception I encountered originated from the following code snippet, but despite that, I was still able to reach the home screen.

```
Future<void> logInWithGoogle() async {
  emit(state.copyWith(status : FormzSubmissionStatus.inProgress));
  try {
    await _authenticationRepository.logInWithGoogle();
    
    // NOTE: I added `createUserEntry` on top of the existing code 
    await _authenticationRepository.createUserEntry();

    emit(state.copyWith(status : FormzSubmissionStatus.success));
  }
  on LogInWithGoogleFailure catch (e) {
    emit(state.copyWith(errorMessage
                        : e.message, status
                        : FormzSubmissionStatus.failure, ), );
  }
  catch (_) {
    // NOTE: I got the exception here
    emit(state.copyWith(status : FormzSubmissionStatus.failure));
  }
}
```

I kept the rest of the code the same as in flutter_firebase_login; the only addition I made was introducing this method:

```
Future<void> createUserEntry() async {
  final user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  final CollectionReference usersCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user');

  final DocumentReference userDocRef = usersCollection.doc(user !.uid);
  final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await userDocRef.get();

  if (userDoc.exists) {
    // User entry already exists, no need to create a new one.
    return;
  }

  final nameParts = user.displayName !.split(' ');
  await userDocRef.set({
    'firstName' : nameParts.first,
    'lastName' : nameParts.last,
    'email' : user.email,
    'title' : '',
    'company' : '',
    'location' : null,
    'bio' : '',
    'interests' : null,
    'profilePicture' : null,
  });
}
```

Then, I call the method inside **logInWithGoogle()** after `await _authenticationRepository.logInWithGoogle();`

Interestingly enough, without **createUserEntry**, it successfully emits *FormzSubmissionStatus.success*, but when included, it does not.

Here are the logs:

> [log] Change { currentState: LoginState(FormzInput<String, EmailValidationError>.pure(value: , isValid: false, error: EmailValidationError.invalid), FormzInput<String, PasswordValidationError>.pure(value: , isValid: false, error: PasswordValidationError.invalid), FormzSubmissionStatus.initial, false, null), nextState: LoginState(FormzInput<String, EmailValidationError>.pure(value: , isValid: false, error: EmailValidationError.invalid), FormzInput<String, PasswordValidationError>.pure(value: , isValid: false, error: PasswordValidationError.invalid), FormzSubmissionStatus.inProgress, false, null) }
> [log] AuthBloc Instance of '_AppUserChanged'
> [log] Transition { currentState: AuthState(AuthStatus.unauthenticated, User(null, , null, null)), event: Instance of '_AppUserChanged', nextState: AuthState(AuthStatus.authenticated, User(myemailaddress@gmail.com, MyID, My Name, My Picture)) }
> [log] Change { currentState: AuthState(AuthStatus.unauthenticated, User(null, , null, null)), nextState: AuthState(AuthStatus.authenticated, User(myemailaddress@gmail.com, MyID, My Name, My Picture)) }
> 2
> [log] LoginCubit Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close

Here is the UI code that corresponds to the state emitted by the **LoginCubit**:

```
class LoginForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.status.isFailure) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
            ..showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text(state.errorMessage ?? 'Authentication 
                           Failure'),
              ),
            );
        }
      },
      child: Align(
        alignment: const Alignment(0, -1 / 3),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/images/welcome.svg',
                height: 200.h,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: spaceXL.h),
              _EmailInput(),
              SizedBox(height: spaceS.h),
              _PasswordInput(),
              SizedBox(height: spaceM.h),
              _LoginButton(),
              SizedBox(height: spaceM.h),
              const Text('Or'),
              SizedBox(height: spaceM.h),
              _GoogleLoginButton(),
              SizedBox(height: spaceS.h),
              _SignUpButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _GoogleLoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyButton.secondary(
      key: const Key('loginForm_googleLogin_raisedButton'),
      label: 'SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE',
      icon: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/google_logo.png',
        height: 25.h,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      onPressed: () => context.read<LoginCubit>().logInWithGoogle(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code with **BlocProvider**:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  static Page<void> page() => const MaterialPage<void>(child: LoginPage());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(spaceL),
        child: BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => 
                LoginCubit(context.read<AuthenticationRepository>()),
          child: const LoginForm(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could someone shed some light on what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you share the UI code that responds to the states emitted by your Bloc, including the `BlocProvider` that instantiates your Bloc?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I have just included it in my post.

Comment: I need to see the UI code that responds to the states emitted by the Bloc (is it in `LoginForm`?).

Comment: Yes, it's in `LoginForm`. Just edited it.

Comment: In your error message, there's something called `AuthBloc`, is that interacting with `LoginCubit` in any way? The error of `Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close` indicates to me that `LoginPage` is being disposed of (navigation?) before the async operation completes, which then tries to a emit a state after the LoginCubit has been disposed of.

Comment: It does. `AuthBloc` looks like the following:


```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc({required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository})
      : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        super(
          authenticationRepository.currentUser.isNotEmpty
              ? AuthState.authenticated(authenticationRepository.currentUser)
              : const AuthState.unauthenticated(),
        ) {
    on<_AppUserChanged>(_onUserChanged);
    ... 
  }
```
How can I make sure `createUserEntry` completes before it's disposed of?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer based on the comments.**

Instead of creating your `LoginCubit` through the `BlocProvider.create` method, instantiate it in the same parent widget (level) that contains your `AuthBloc`. Later, when `LoginCubit` is no longer needed, simply call `close` on the instance manually.

Here's a rough example on how to set it up to stop the disposal from happening:

```
/// Mock authentication Bloc.
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<Object, Object> {
  AuthBloc() : super(Object());
}

/// Mock LoginCubit.
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<Object> {
  LoginCubit() : super(Object());
}


/// Mock LoginPage.
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

/// This widget is placed above any other widget that consumes your Blocs.
class MyParent extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyParent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyParent> createState() => _MyParentState();
}

class _MyParentState extends State<MyParent> {
  
  final _authBloc = AuthBloc();
  final _loginCubit = LoginCubit();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    /// First check if they're already closed, just in case they were closed
    /// elsewhere. This is only needed because the 'BlocProvider's do not
    /// manage the lifetime of these Blocs.
    /// 
    /// They don't manage the lifetime of these blocs because they are created
    /// with the 'BlocProvider.value' constructor, which means that the blocs
    /// are not created by the 'BlocProvider's, but rather passed to them.
    if (!_authBloc.isClosed) _authBloc.close();
    if (!_loginCubit.isClosed) _loginCubit.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        /// Use the BlocProvider.value constructor.
        BlocProvider.value(value: _authBloc),
        BlocProvider.value(value: _loginCubit),
      ],

      /// This is your login page widget, it contains the builders that rebuild
      /// based on the states emitted by the blocs.
      child: const LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

As soon as you no longer need a bloc (i.e. `LoginCubit`), then simply close it manually:

`context.read<LoginCubit>().close();`

Let me know if refactoring your bloc lifetime this way solves your issue.

Comment: I've just successfully refactored the code, and it's now working like a charm! Thank you so much! 

Additionally, I came across another approach, which I've included as an alternative solution.

Which approach do you think is better?

Comment: Your approach is better because it localizes each action strictly to the location that is necessary. In addition, when you reach the `NavigationPage`, you have likely already validated any pre-conditions that `createUserEntry` depends on. Go with yours. My answer was simply to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

As @offworldwelcome pointed out, the `close()` method is called when explicitly disposing of the AuthBloc instance. This can happen in different scenarios.

1. Manual Disposal: Calling `close()` on it when it's no longer needed, the `close()` method will be executed, and the `_userSubscription` will be canceled.
2. Navigation Pop: When using the `AuthBloc` in a widget that is part of a navigation stack (e.g., pushed onto a `Navigator`), the `close()` method might be called when the widget is popped from the navigation stack. This usually happens automatically when the user navigates back from a screen.
3. Scoped Bloc: When using a coped dependency injection library like `flutter_bloc`, which provides automatic disposal of blocs based on the widget's lifecycle, the `close()` method will be called when the widget is disposed of.

In my case, as soon as users are authenticated, they are immediately routed to `NavigationPage.page()`, which in turn leads them to the `HomePage()`. As a result, LoginCubit is automatically closed.

My solution involves refraining from calling `await _authenticationRepository.createUserEntry();` inside `logInWithGoogle()`. Instead, after successfully authenticating and routing users to `NavigationPage()`, add `context.read<AuthenticationRepository>().createUserEntry();` within `NavigationPage()`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).